# Output Raw Text in VF page without HTML from Visualforce Controller?

Tags: visualforce

Is there a way in visualforce to output text from a controller that does **NOT** get rendered in a span tag?

I want to just output a text string from my controller inside an `<h4>` tag.  When I use `<apex:outputText value="{!someFieldValue}" />` it generates a `<span>` tag with my value inside it and I just want the text with no additional HTML generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not always required to bind field value with outputtext when you put anything inside {!} it render value directly on visualforce page so you can do that in following way and it will render value with h4 tag

```
<h4>{!someFieldValue}</h4>
```

Comment: Do you still get the automatic escaping `outputText` provides in this case? Isn't this a security vulnerability?

Comment: @AdrianLarson no it will not do automatic escaping but he has mentioned that he has only text string not html string so it will work.

Comment: Not so, he mentioned he wants to merge in `someFieldValue`. For all we know it could be rich text.

Comment: I want to just output a text string from my controller this is what initial question was. but your question will also help

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use the `outputText` tag without your content being wrapped in a `<span>`, you need to refrain from applying styles. From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) on `apex:outputText`:

> **apex:outputText**
>   Displays text on a Visualforce page. You can customize the appearance of  using CSS styles, in which case the generated text is wrapped in an HTML  tag.

A simple page can be used to demonstrate this behavior.

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:outputText value="test 1" />
    <apex:outputText value="test 2" style="" />
    <apex:outputText value="test 3" styleClass="" />
</apex:page>
```

In the above, `test 1` will just be a text node, while the latter two will be wrapped in a `<span>`.

**You should continue to use `outputText` unless you are using a trusted input source and can verify it will not contain markup.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the expression syntax like the below:

```
"{!HTMLENCODE(controllerString)}"
```

this can mask the HTML Keywords in the string.. This way you can do your string manipulation..